# c++ Linked List no longer taking Ram space?

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list, operating-system

I have created large Linked List data that initially takes up to 2.5 GB. I used for a while and left computer alone for a while(approximately 40 min).
When I returned this space was not under RAM. It shrank to 20 MB. All data are still accessible and integrity of data are good.
Can somebody explain what is happening, please?
Where is this data stored?

OS: Windows 10
compiler: Mingw32
language: c++

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to say without seeing information from the state of the machine during the run. One possibility is that it was compressed in memory. Another possibility is that identical pages of memory were deduplicated. Lastly, it could have been written out to swap.

There's no way to know without us seeing exactly what was going on with the machine at the time.

Comment: Thank you. At least that gives me some insight.